# sqlite query help

Tags: sqlite

Im looking to do a replacement of part of a string in sqlite. Substr

I have a table with a column called name.

Where ever the name starts with Matt, I want to replace it with John.

For example:
"Matt Smith" goes to "John Smith"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace would actually give you exactly that

```
REPLACE("Matt Smith", "Matt", "John")
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I am looking to do a replace across all fields in the DB. So REPLACE(ALL, "MATT", "JOHN")

Comment: I think you will have to write an update that includes all the fields then, but you can still use this like: `SET name = REPLACE(name, 'Matt', 'John')`

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
final String[] whereArgs = { "Matt%" };
final ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(NAME_COLUMN, "John");
int columnsUpdated = this.sqlitedatabase.update(YOUR_TABLE,args,"where name like ?", whereArgs);
```